# When should I split a JSON into smaller parts?

Tags: javascript, json, web

I want to use cmudict file in a web. It contains 170000 words with its phonetic transcription (in ARPAbet symbols).

http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict

I want to use it in JSON format, search any word introduced by the user and return an explanation of how to pronounce it syllabe by syllabe. The second part is not very complex in search terms as there are only 39 different phonemes, but the first one with the 170000 entries may consume too much time if the user introduces a text instead of a single word to transcript.

I wonder if it's worth to split the JSON into for example 26 parts (one per initial letter) and search only in the corresponding file.

Also I don't know if JSON is the best format for this, but I want to use it in a free blog like Tumblr or Blogger ones (or similar, the thing is that I don't want to spend money in this) and Javascript is what they support. I would listen suggestions on this too.

Comment: Yes, narrowing the options to scan through will make it more efficient (i.e. split on first letter).

Comment: Probably too broad a topic to cover here, but I would suggest using JSON only for it's intended purpose of being a serialization format.  You would likely need a full blown service (which can communicate using JSON serialization) to answer this problem, as I would think you would not download 170,000 words to the client in JSON and have the client hold all that in memory in some optimized lookup structure.  My suggestion would be to store the data in a service which has the dictionary in an appropriate data structure to be able to due lookups quickly.

Comment: So how big is that 170k words array(?) ? What makes you thinking you *need* to split it?

Comment: 170k is not too many. i would try pushing it all to the client and see how it behaves. if it's slow, split it up or have it done by a backend, but you can probably do it all on the client, and gzip can likely cut down the download time, or zip the json and give JS the zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that is tough call since you must consider download size.  I would shorten the names of all your properties to be as small as possible, so instead of repeating "description" : "the short description", I would go with "sd" : "the short description".  You are trying to use javascript to serve a data file, which is okay since you can rely on caching and what not, but the initial download size may be rather large.  I would do something like var myDictionary = { }; at the top of the file, that way you can reference the variable since it is in the global space.  It is an interesting experiment for sure.